# Passing classes in with Slots to vue components

Tags: class, vuejs2, slots

I have a vue component

`<Student></Student>`

I want to change the style based on if they are an undergrad or postgrad.

I know I can pass in a prop and use this value to assign a dynamic class or use it in a computed prop.

`<Student type="'postGrad'"></Student>`

But can I do this with slots and assign a class or is there a better way to use props to achieve this?

```
<Student>
 <slot name="type">PostGrad/slot>
</Student>
```

I have always used props but feel I could be missing a good technique with slots.

Comment: With your use case, props seems like a good option.
Why would you need slots?
From docs : 

`using the <slot> element to serve as distribution outlets for content.`

Style is not content.

Comment: I would suggest to rewrite the question. 
Clarify your question to help people understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to add class

```
<Student class="myClass">
 <slot name="type">PostGrad/slot>
</Student>
```